# How to get the data from server and upload data to server using Json

Tags: android, json

How to get the data from server and upload data to server using JSON? 
please tell me.

This is QRActivity------------------------------------------------

```
 final View.OnClickListener listener = new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public
        void onClick(View v) {
            btnSearch.setClickable(true);



            // Server call with record_id
   //DistributionDetails detDis <-- response json object from server call


    QrActivityViewDetails detDis = new 
      QrActivityViewDetails(1002,"NORORG147530","No2,abcd Road , Colombo 03","0112233456");

             Intent myIntent = new Intent(QrActivity.this, DistributionDetails.class);
            myIntent.putExtra("QrActivityViewDetails", detDis);
            startActivity(myIntent);


        }


    };
```

---

This is QrActivityViewDetails Class file

```
public class QrActivityViewDetails implements Serializable {

@SerializedName("DistributionID")
private int DistributionID;

@SerializedName("full_name")
private String full_name;

@SerializedName("full_address")
private String full_address;

@SerializedName("contact")
private String contact;


public QrActivityViewDetails(int DistributionID, String full_name, String full_address, String contact_number)
{
    this.DistributionID = DistributionID;
    this.full_name = full_name;
    this.full_address = full_address;
    this.contact = contact_number;


}

public
int getRecord_id() {
    return DistributionID;
}

public
void setRecord_id(int record_id) {
    this.DistributionID = record_id;
}

public
String getFull_name() {
    return full_name;
}

public
void setFull_name(String full_name) {
    this.full_name = full_name;
}

public
String getFull_address() {
    return full_address;
}

public
void setFull_address(String full_address) {
    this.full_address = full_address;
}

public
String getContact() {
    return contact;
}

public
void setContact(String contact) {
    this.contact = contact;
}
```

}

This is View Data  Activity  called DistributionDetails---------------

public class DistributionDetails extends AppCompatActivity  {

```
private QrActivityViewDetails detQRV;



TextView ID ,Address ,name,contact;
Button btnDIR;





@Override
protected
void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_distribution_details);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    ID = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblID);
    Address = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblAddress);
    name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblUname);
    contact = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblTelenum);
    btnDIR = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDelivered);



    IntendFill();

        btnDIR.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public
            void onClick(View v) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(DistributionDetails.this, FinalActivity.class);

                startActivity(intent);
            }

        });

}



public void IntendFill() {
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    if (intent.hasExtra("QrActivityViewDetails")) {
        detQRV = (QrActivityViewDetails) intent.getSerializableExtra("QrActivityViewDetails");

        ID.setText(String.valueOf(detQRV.getRecord_id()));
        Address.setText(String.valueOf(detQRV.getFull_address()));
        name.setText(String.valueOf(detQRV.getFull_name()));
        contact.setText(String.valueOf(detQRV.getContact()));

    }
}
```

}

Comment: You can use a lof of method get and post with JSON. You should research: Retrofit, Volley or AsyncTask.

Comment: For json request/response volley is better choice

Comment: Yes I'm using that library but it's not send data

Comment: thanks, but how to response json object from server call??

Comment: Please could you  explain by sample code?